# Sitecore.core.mdf is not in a valid directory from Instance Manager

Tags: installation, sim

I'm trying to "Install Instance" via the Sitecore Instance manager. For reference the SQL Server Connection String goes to a remote sql server which I access through a vpn.
I go through all the steps but then I get the following error:

[image]

However there **IS** a valid directory at this path. Furthermore it actually makes this file for me.
I know I can get around this by manually changing the `ConnectionStrings.config` file however since the installation has gone wrong, it doesn't complete the `sitecore/login` installation properly as there are sections and images missing from it.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Based on the error it looks like that it's trying to find path to directory but found path to file. Check maybe some configuration in SIM